# hashtable issue in C; double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I am coding a hash table with singly linkedList and I have this problem `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` I tried to fix it but did'nt make it, the problem its the `free()` , so could you explain me why I have it, So if anyone can help, so please help me, I'm trying to fix it for hours now...
Thank you.

I've watched some video on youtube and many topics on websitte and also here but I didn't find a solution for mine.

This are my functions:

```
/**List header */
#ifndef LISTE_H
#define LISTE_H

struct _list_node {
    void * data;
    struct _list_node *next;
};

typedef struct _list_node s_node;

s_node * list_create(void);
void * list_get_data(s_node * node);
void list_set_data(s_node * node, void * data);
s_node * list_insert(s_node * head, void * data);
s_node * list_append(s_node * head, void * data);
int list_process(s_node * head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param, s_node ** last);
s_node * list_ordered_append(s_node ** head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param);
s_node * list_remove (s_node * head, void * data);
s_node * list_headRemove(s_node * head);
void * list_destroy(s_node * head);
void afficher_s_node(s_node * list);
int list_is_empty( s_node * node );
unsigned int list_size(s_node * node);
int list_process(s_node * head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param, s_node ** last);

#endif

/****  c file list */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

s_node * list_create(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

void * list_get_data(s_node * node)
{
    return node->data;
}

void list_set_data(s_node * node, void * data)
{
    node->data = data;
}

s_node * list_insert(s_node * head, void * data)
{
    s_node * node = (s_node *) malloc(sizeof(s_node));
    list_set_data(node, data);
    node->next = head;
    return node;
}

s_node * list_append(s_node * head, void * data)
{
    if (!head) return list_insert(head, data);

    s_node * node = head;

    while (node->next) {
        node = node->next;
    }

    node->next = (s_node *) malloc(sizeof(s_node));
    node->next->next = list_create();
    list_set_data(node->next, data);

    return head;
}

int list_process(s_node * head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param, s_node ** last)
{
    if (!head) return 0;

    s_node * node;
    for (node = head; node; node = node->next) {
        if (fct(node, param) == 1) {
            *last = node;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

s_node * list_ordered_append(s_node ** head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param)
{
    // quand elle est vide
    if (!(*head)) {
        *head = list_insert(*head, param);
        return *head;
    }

    // insertion en tete
    s_node * node;
    if (fct(*head, param) == 1) {
        *head = list_insert(*head, param);
        return (*head);
    }

    // cas general
    int res;
    for(node = *head; node->next; node = node->next) {
        if ((res = fct(node->next, param)) == 1) {
            node->next = list_insert(node->next, param);
            return node->next;
        } else if (res == 0) {
            return node->next;
        }
    }
    if (fct(node, param) == 0) return node;

    *head = list_append(*head, param);
    return node->next;
}

s_node * list_remove (s_node * head, void * data)
{
    if (!head) return head;

    for (s_node * node = head; node->next; node = node->next) {
        if (node->next->data == data) {
            s_node * n = node->next->next;
            free(node->next);
            node->next = n;
            break;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

s_node * list_headRemove(s_node * head)
{
    if (!head) return head;
    s_node * n = head->next;
    free(head);
    return n;
}

void * list_destroy(s_node * head)
{
     while (head)
        head = list_headRemove(head);
}

void afficher_s_node(s_node * list)
{
    printf("\nliste = [");
    while (list) {
        printf("%d,", *((int *)(list->data)));
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
    return;
}

int list_is_empty( s_node * node ) {
  return NULL == node;
}

unsigned int list_size(s_node * node)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (node) {
        node = node->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

/*PLUS
int list_process(s_node * head, int (*fct)(s_node * node, void * param),
    void * param, s_node ** last)
{
    if (!head) return 0;

    s_node * node;
    for (node = head; node; node = node->next) {
        if (fct(node, param) == 1) {
            *last = node;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
*/
/* hash table header */
#ifndef HACHAGE_H
#define HACHAGE_H

#include "list.h"

typedef struct {
    s_node * node;
    unsigned int len;
} super_list;

typedef struct {
    super_list * list;
    unsigned int len;
} strhash_table;

strhash_table * strhash_table_init(const unsigned int len);
strhash_table * strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table * table);
strhash_table * strhash_table_free(strhash_table * table);
char * strhash_table_add(strhash_table * table, char * str);
strhash_table * strhash_table_remove(strhash_table * table, char * str);
void strhash_table_info(strhash_table * table);
void strhash_print(strhash_table * table);

#endif


/****  c file hash table */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "hachage.h"
#include "list.h"

int hashCode(char * str, const int size_hash_table)
{
     int i, cle = 0;
     for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cle *= 2;
        cle += (int) str[i];
    }
     return cle % size_hash_table;
}

int compare_str_add(s_node *node, void *param)
{
    int res = strcmp((char *) node->data, (char *) param);
    /*if the first non-matching character in node->data 
      is lower (in ASCII) than that of param.*/
    if (res < 0) return -1;
    
    /*if the first non-matching character in node->data 
      is greater (in ASCII) than that of param.*/
    if (res > 0) return 1;
    return 0;//if strings are equal
}


strhash_table * strhash_table_init(const unsigned int len)
{
    super_list *list = (super_list *) malloc(sizeof(super_list) * len);
    strhash_table * table = (strhash_table *) malloc(sizeof(strhash_table));

    if(!table) return NULL;
    table->len = len;
    if (!list) return NULL;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].node = list_create();
        list[i].len = 0;
    }
    table->list = list;

    return table;
}

strhash_table * strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table * table)
{
     unsigned int i;
    super_list *list;
    s_node *node, *next;

    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {  
        list = table->list + i;
        node = list->node;
        while (node) {
            next = node->next;
            free(node->data);           
            free(node);
            node = next;
        }
    }
    free(table->list);
    free(table);
    return table; 
 
}

strhash_table * strhash_table_free(strhash_table * table)
{
    unsigned int i;
    super_list *list;
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        list = table->list + i;
        if (list->len > 0) {
            free(list->node->data);
            list_destroy(list->node);
            list->len = 0;
            return table;
        }
    }
    return table;
}

char * strhash_table_add(strhash_table * table, char * str)
{
    char * to_insert = strdup(str);
    int index = hashCode(str, table->len);

    s_node *ordered_Add = list_ordered_append(&(table->list[index].node), compare_str_add, to_insert);
    if (ordered_Add->data == to_insert)
        table->list[index].len++;
    else
        free(to_insert);
    return (char *) ordered_Add->data;
}

int find_str_node(s_node *node, void *param)
{
    return strcmp((char *) node->data, (char *) param) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

strhash_table * strhash_table_remove(strhash_table * table, char * str)
{
    const int index = hashCode(str, table->len);
    if (table->list[index].len == 0) return table;

    s_node *find_node;
    const int result = list_process(table->list[index].node, &find_str_node, str, &find_node);
    if (result == 1) {
        free(find_node->data);
        table->list[index].node = list_remove(table->list[index].node, find_node->data);
        table->list[index].len--;
    }
    return table;
}

void strhash_table_info(strhash_table * table)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int len, min, max;
    float deviation, moy;

    len = max = min = table->list[0].len;
    for (i = 1; i < table->len; i++) {
        if (table->list[i].len > max) max = table->list[i].len;
        else if (table->list[i].len < min) min = table->list[i].len;
        len += table->list[i].len;
    }

    moy = (float)len / table->len;
    deviation = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        deviation += (table->list[i].len - moy) * (table->list[i].len - moy);
    }
    deviation = (float) sqrt(deviation / table->len);

    printf("Table hachage : ");
    printf("%p\n",table);
    printf("\tNombre total d'élément : " );
    printf("%u\n",len );
    printf("\tNombre minimum : ");
    printf("%u\n", min);
    printf("\tNombre maximum : ");
    printf("%u\n", max );
    printf("\tÉcart type du nombre d'éléments par entrée : ");
    printf("%.2f\n", deviation );
    return;
}

void strhash_print(strhash_table * table)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    super_list *list;
    s_node *node;
    printf("\nHash table de %p\n", table);
    printf("Start\n");
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        list = table->list + i;
        printf("\t%d ---\n", i);
        /****/
        for (j = 0, node = list->node; j < list->len; j++, node = node->next) 
        {
            printf( "\t\t%d. %s\n", j, (char *) node->data);
        }
    }
    printf("End\n");
    return;
}
/**** test file */

strhash_table * test_init(const unsigned int len)
{
    strhash_table * table = strhash_table_init(len);
    if (!table) {
        printf("Tha HashTable hasn't been created\n");
        assert(0);
    }
    printf("***Tha HashTable has been created***\n");
    return table;
}

strhash_table * test_destroy(strhash_table * table){
    
    table = strhash_table_destroy(table);
    if (table->list->node) {
        printf("The HashTable hasn't been destroyed (%p)\n", table->list->node);
        assert(0);
    }
    printf("The HashTable has been destroyed\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    strhash_table * table =strhash_table_init(10);
    strhash_print(table);
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele1");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele2");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele3");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele4");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele5");
    //strhash_table_remove(table,"ele1");
    //strhash_table_free(table);
    test_destroy(table); 

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: In the `list_destroy` function, when the loop ends it will be because `node` is a null pointer. Then you call `free` on that null pointer. It¨s good that it's defined behavior, and a no-op, but you should still remove that rather useless call.

Comment: I also recommend you use address and UB sanitizers if your compiler supports them. Or a memory debugger like Valgrind or similar.

Comment: I understand that, I will try to do it, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

You should move `list_destroy(list->node);` outside the inner loop. You are freeing the node list multiple times inside a loop where you iterate on the node links.

Here is a modified version:

```
strhash_table *strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table *table) {
    unsigned int i;
    super_list *list;
    s_node *node;

    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        list = table->list + i;
        for (node = list->node; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
            free(node->data);
        }
        list_destroy(list->node);
    }
    free(table->list);
    free(table);
    return table;
}

void list_destroy(s_node *head) {
    while (head) {
        head = list_headRemove(head);
    }
}

s_node *list_headRemove(s_node *head) {
    if (!head) return head;
    s_node *n = head->next;
    free(head);
    return n;
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the code posted, there are conflicting versions of functions `list_destroy` and `list_headRemove`, furthermore there are 2 calls to `free(node);` in the second function `list_destroy`, both of which are useless since `node` is a null pointer when the `while` loop exits.

**UPDATE 2**

There is a problem in `strhash_table_free`: you free `list->node` but you do not update `list->node`, so the list is freed a second time in `strhash_table_destroy` where `list->len` is not tested.

The field `len` in `super_list` seems redundant. You should just test if the `node` member is `NULL` and set it to `NULL` when the list is freed.

**UPDATE 3**

The final post is hardly minimal and does not show the problem... but I found some issues:

- `strhash_table_destroy` returns `table` after freeing it: this is bad because `table` is now an invalid pointer. `strhash_table_destroy` should not return anything.
- `test_destroy` dereferences `table` after `strhash_table_destroy` has freed it. This has undefined behavior. Remove this test function, just call `strhash_table_destroy` from `main()`.
- you free `node->data` in `strhash_table_remove` before passing it to `list_remove`, which is bad because `node->data` has become invalid.
- worse: `list_remove()` does not test is the `head` node should be removed. In a minimal test case with a single element in the hash table, `"ele1"` is the head node, hence this node remains in the list, the `len` is decremented and becomes out of sync and the node has an invalid `data` pointer which will `strhash_table_destroy` will attempt to free, causing the double free issue.
- `strhash_table_free` seems incorrect and inconsistent with `strhash_table_destroy`.

There are probably other issues in the code.

Here is a modified version with some simplifications and fixes:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**List header */
#ifndef LISTE_H
#define LISTE_H

struct _list_node {
    void *data;
    struct _list_node *next;
};

typedef struct _list_node s_node;

s_node *list_create(void);
void *list_get_data(s_node *node);
void list_set_data(s_node *node, void *data);
s_node *list_insert(s_node *head, void *data);
s_node *list_append(s_node *head, void *data);
s_node *list_process(s_node *head, int (*fct)(s_node *node, void *param), void *param);
s_node *list_ordered_append(s_node **head, int (*fct)(s_node *node, void *param), void *param);
s_node *list_headRemove(s_node *head);
s_node *list_remove(s_node *head, void *data);
void list_destroy(s_node *head);
void afficher_s_node(s_node *list);
int list_is_empty( s_node *node );
unsigned int list_size(s_node *node);
#endif

/****  c file list */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "list.h"

s_node *list_create(void) {
    return NULL;
}

void *list_get_data(s_node *node) {
    return node->data;
}

void list_set_data(s_node *node, void *data) {
    node->data = data;
}

s_node *list_insert(s_node *head, void *data) {
    s_node *node = (s_node *)malloc(sizeof(s_node));
    if (node) {
        list_set_data(node, data);
        node->next = head;
        return node;
    } else {
        return head;
    }
}

s_node *list_append(s_node *head, void *data) {
    if (!head) return list_insert(head, data);

    s_node *node = head;
    while (node->next) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    node->next = list_insert(NULL, data);

    return head;
}

s_node *list_process(s_node *head, int (*fct)(s_node *node, void *param), void *param) {
    for (s_node *node = head; node; node = node->next) {
        if (fct(node, param) == 1) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

s_node *list_ordered_append(s_node **head, int (*fct)(s_node *node, void *param), void *param) {
    s_node *node;
    int res;

    // empty list
    if (!*head) {
        return *head = list_insert(*head, param);
    }

    // insert at head
    res = fct(*head, param);
    if (res > 0) {
        return *head = list_insert(*head, param);
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        return *head;
    }

    // generic case
    for (node = *head; node->next; node = node->next) {
        res = fct(node->next, param);
        if (res > 1) {
            return node->next = list_insert(node->next, param);
        }
        if (res == 0) {
            return node->next;
        }
    }

    // append node
    return node->next = list_insert(NULL, param);
}

s_node *list_headRemove(s_node *head) {
    if (head) {
        s_node *n = head->next;
        free(head);
        return n;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

s_node *list_remove(s_node *head, void *data) {
    if (!head) return head;

    if (head->data == data) {
        head = list_headRemove(head);
    } else {
        for (s_node *node = head; node->next; node = node->next) {
            if (node->next->data == data) {
                node->next = list_headRemove(node->next);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void list_destroy(s_node *head) {
    while (head)
        head = list_headRemove(head);
}

int list_is_empty(s_node *node) {
    return node == NULL;
}

unsigned int list_size(s_node *node) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (node) {
        node = node->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

/* hash table header */
#ifndef HACHAGE_H
#define HACHAGE_H

//#include "list.h"

typedef struct {
    s_node *node;
    unsigned int len;
} super_list;

typedef struct {
    super_list *list;
    unsigned int len;
} strhash_table;

strhash_table *strhash_table_init(const unsigned int len);
void strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table *table);
strhash_table *strhash_table_free(strhash_table *table);
char *strhash_table_add(strhash_table *table, const char *str);
int strhash_table_remove(strhash_table *table, const char *str);
void strhash_table_info(strhash_table *table);
void strhash_print(strhash_table *table);

#endif

/****  c file hash table */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include "hachage.h"
//#include "list.h"

int hashCode(const char *str, unsigned int size_hash_table) {
    unsigned int i, cle = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cle *= 2;
        cle += (int)str[i];
    }
    return cle % size_hash_table;
}

int compare_str_add(s_node *node, void *param) {
    /* return <0 if node->data is before param, >0 if after, =0 if strings are equal */
    return strcmp((const char *)node->data, (const char *)param);
}

strhash_table *strhash_table_init(const unsigned int len) {
    strhash_table *table = (strhash_table *)malloc(sizeof(strhash_table));
    super_list *list = (super_list *)malloc(sizeof(super_list) * len);

    if (!table || !list) {
        free(table);
        free(list);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].node = list_create();
        list[i].len = 0;
    }
    table->list = list;
    table->len = len;

    return table;
}

void strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table *table) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        super_list *list = table->list + i;
        s_node *node = list->node;
        while (node) {
            s_node *next = node->next;
            free(node->data);
            free(node);
            node = next;
        }
        list->node = NULL;
    }
    free(table->list);
    free(table);
}

char *strhash_table_add(strhash_table *table, const char *str) {
    char *to_insert = strdup(str);
    int index = hashCode(str, table->len);

    s_node *ordered_Add = list_ordered_append(&table->list[index].node, compare_str_add, to_insert);
    if (ordered_Add->data == to_insert) {
        /* node was inserted: increase len */
        table->list[index].len++;
    } else {
        /* node already present: free new data */
        free(to_insert);
    }
    return (char *)ordered_Add->data;
}

int find_str_node(s_node *node, void *param) {
    return strcmp((const char *)node->data, (const char *)param) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

// return 1 if successful
int strhash_table_remove(strhash_table *table, const char *str) {
    int index = hashCode(str, table->len);
    s_node *find_node = list_process(table->list[index].node, find_str_node, (void *)(uintptr_t)str);
    if (find_node) {
        /* node was found: free node and data */
        void *data = find_node->data;
        table->list[index].node = list_remove(table->list[index].node, data);
        table->list[index].len--;
        free(data);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void strhash_table_info(strhash_table *table) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int len, min, max;
    double deviation, moy;

    len = max = min = table->list[0].len;
    for (i = 1; i < table->len; i++) {
        if (table->list[i].len > max) max = table->list[i].len;
        else if (table->list[i].len < min) min = table->list[i].len;
        len += table->list[i].len;
    }

    moy = (double)len / table->len;
    deviation = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        deviation += (table->list[i].len - moy) * (table->list[i].len - moy);
    }
    deviation = sqrt(deviation / table->len);

    printf("Table hachage : ");
    printf("%p\n", (void *)table);
    printf("\tNombre total d'élément : " );
    printf("%u\n",len );
    printf("\tNombre minimum : ");
    printf("%u\n", min);
    printf("\tNombre maximum : ");
    printf("%u\n", max );
    printf("\tÉcart type du nombre d'éléments par entrée : ");
    printf("%.2f\n", deviation);
    return;
}

void strhash_print(strhash_table *table) {
    unsigned int i, j;
    super_list *list;
    s_node *node;
    printf("\nHash table de %p\n", (void *)table);
    printf("Start\n");
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        list = table->list + i;
        printf("\t%d ---\n", i);
        /****/
        for (j = 0, node = list->node; j < list->len; j++, node = node->next) {
            printf( "\t\t%d. %s\n", j, (char *)node->data);
        }
    }
    printf("End\n");
}

/**** test file */

int main(void) {
    strhash_table *table = strhash_table_init(10);
    strhash_print(table);
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele1");
    strhash_table_remove(table, "ele1");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele1");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele2");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele3");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele4");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele5");
    strhash_table_remove(table, "ele1");
    strhash_print(table);
    strhash_table_destroy(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I actually did that before, and then I rewrote it and both of them give me the same problem. And my ``void list_destroy(s_node * head)`` have a ``free()`` too, i didn't realize that it was missing

Comment: I just updated, and I still have the sale issue :(

Comment: I will put more code here if I can

Comment: I just  update the post, the function ``list_destroy`` at the end it's the old version, and even when I used the version you posed, I got the same issue, So the problem of that came from  ``list_destroy`` that uses ``list_headRemove`` and use free too.
I tried to use another version of ``strhash_table_destroy`` proposed by @Scouarn. And I got the same issue.

Comment: I thougth about that, and in my test, I'm not using ``strhash_table_free`` at all, I'm using ``strhash_table_init``, ``strhash_table_add`` ,``strhash_table_remove`` and at the and ``test_destroy``but if I want to use ``strhash_table_free`` its work.

Comment: I did what you propsed,and I hade some results : 
-I get a double free detected in tcache 2 here, if one of them or both it's called, but if they not I don't get it :
strhash_table_add(table, "ele1");
strhash_table_add(table, "ele2");
strhash_table_add(table, "ele3");
strhash_table_add(table, "ele4");
strhash_table_add(table, "ele5");
strhash_table_remove(table,"ele1");
strhash_table_free(table);
test_destroy(table);

Comment: But i don't get it here when I use both strhash_table_remove and strhash_table_remove or just one of them: 

 strhash_table_add(table, "ele1");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele2");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele3");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele4");
    strhash_table_add(table, "ele5");
    strhash_table_remove(table,"ele1");
    strhash_table_free(table);

Comment: Done :), I just updated ^^

Comment: I just update it, this it is the minimal compilable code

Comment: I updated the answer, let's clean up the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time.
I workes for me :))

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do it in my opinion assuming you don't reuse `list_headRemove` and `list_headRemove` :

```
strhash_table *strhash_table_destroy(strhash_table *table) {
    unsigned int i;
    super_list *list;
    s_node *node, *next;

    for (i = 0; i < table->len; i++) {
        
        list = table->list + i;
        node = list->node;

        while (node) {
            next = node->next;

            free(node->data);           
            free(node);

            node = next;
        }

    }

    free(table->list);
    free(table);

    return table; /* This pointer is not valid anymore be careful */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just tried, and I have the same issue, do you think that could come from somewhere else ?

Comment: Is it the `free(node->data)` ? I think should edit your post to show how stuff is allocated.

Comment: I just did updated